# Joomla: Category link inside mod_articles_news

Tags: php, joomla

I want to have the link of the article category in the output of mod_articles_news
Right now I just have the category name with this:

```
<?php echo $item->category_title; ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to build a link or how to get the category ID?

Comment: Hi, yes I am asking how to get category id

Comment: This does not give me the ID: "$catid = JRequest::getInt('catid');"

Comment: Hi,  Did you tried to var_dump() the $item ? You can try this to check if there is any property named category_id. Then you can just use `$item->category_id` to get that.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it

Comment: `var_dump($item)`

Comment: thank you , it showed also the catid, very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was simpler than I thought, this worked for me:

```
<?php echo "<a href='index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=".$item->catid."'>" ; ?><?php echo $item->category_title; ?></a>
```

so after checking the helper.php category ID can be grabbed by this:

```
$item->catid
```